# How do we calculate linear speed to rotation?

Tags: animation

[image]
I often need to figure out the linear velocity to the rotational velocity. If a roller is rotating at #frame/n and the roller has a diameter D, what is the resulting linear velocity?

Comment: this might help as well https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_velocity

Comment: In some cases, this rig  might be easier to animate backwards.. with the box driving the rollers. But you've probably already decided on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is not very clear about what you mean by "is rotating at #frame/n" because this means technically an acceleration/deceleration. Also the meaning of `n` is not clearly stated so I will assume it's a constant number. I can give a general explanation:

If you don't want to include simulated friction or slip losses, you simply need the `Peripheral Speed` of one cylinder. It can be calculated by `P_s = pi * D * RPM` where:

- `pi` ~ 3.1416 *[no unit]*
- `D` is your diameter *[meter]*
- `RPM` "rounds per minute" *[1/minute]* (in case of Blender it might be more useful to give it as `RPS` "rounds per seconds") resp. *[1/second]*

`pi` and `D` are known, so you only have to derive `RPS` from Blender's driver expression `#frame/n` which has to be in *[1/minute]* resp. *[1/second]*. For that you probably have to calculate the duration of one frame. If you have `24 FPS` (see your `Output Properties`) then one frame lasts `1.0 seconds / 24.0 ~= 0.042 seconds`. If you clarify your question, I can give a more detailed answer.

Comment: your answer is totally right (+1 from me), but maybe you should write additionally "if n is a constant number" which you assumed, but maybe JB Riley meant something different - so he you might misunderstood each other - and i think he should have mentioned what "n" is.

Comment: yes. you are right. i updated my answer.